# How to unlink the SSIS parameter configuration between SSIS package in catalog and in the SQL server agent job step?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package deployed to the catalog. Parameters are configured.

A new SQL agent job step is used to run this SSIS package. In the configuration on the step, new values are set for a couple of parameters.

Now suppose I edit the parameters on the package in the catalog, then, for the parameters that were not edited in the previous step (in the job step), the value gets updated. How to unlink the SSIS parameter configuration between SSIS package in catalog and in the SQL server agent job step?

Comment: You set the parameter/environment you want when you run the package; in this case those settings are in the agent as it's running the package. If you need to change those for the agent task you need to amend the agent job.

Comment: Are you looking to forever de-link the project configuration or for a particular execution? Can you distill this down into a more concrete example of the problem situation?

Comment: For example - assume I have a SSIS package configured to run via SQL server agent job step. By default it uses the parameter values from the params values configured in the ssis catalog. Now if a developer goes and changes the param value in the ssis catalog, then why should the value in the SQL server agent job step config change?

Comment: @Larnu - I think I get your point - but assume the concept of environment variables is not used.

Comment: If you're using the default values, then of course it's by design. Use parameters and explicitly define the value you want to use when you call the package; then it will be explicitly defined and the default won't be used.

Comment: I was wondering that - why was updating the parameter value at package level causing update at the agent job level. But if you say it is by design then ok I get your point.